# EXCEL: SUMIF wildcard exclusion

Tags: excel

I am trying to use SUMIF to calculate based on TEXT (within a string of text) found in Column A. This part is working no problem. I am using `=SUMIF(A2:A2000,"*RVSR*",I2:I2000)`

I run into an issue because the next TEXT I need to search for is "VSR". So, the SUM comes back incorrect because it sums all VSR and RVSR cells.

Using wildcards is necessary because the search word/term is within a bunch of other text like "US Team VSR 1".

How do I force the equation to omit when ever 'RVSR' comes up?

Thanks

Comment: SUMIF with `"*VSR*"` and then subtract the result of SUMIF with `"*RVSR*"`. This assumes that VSR and RVSR are not found in the same cell.

Comment: You rock, Sir. Missed that simple workaround.